# Running R script from Shell using CygWin: error "Rscript not found"

Tags: shell, command, cygwin, rscript

This is the first time I am trying to run the R file from CygWin terminal.
I have a file named linreg.R and I am in the same directory as file in CygWin terminal.
There is a shell script in the same directory that take in input linreg.R and another data.txt (located at some other place).

When I am running the bash with appropriate inputs, its again and again giving me the same error:

```
$ ./build_model_from_directory.sh linreg.R /workdir/workdir/prod_data_v.txt lm_try
./build_model_from_directory.sh: line 27: type: Rscript: not found
Rscript is needed for linreg.R. Exiting
```

When I put something like this:

```
$./build_model_from_directory.sh linreg.Rscript /workdir/workdir/prod_data_v.txt lm_try
Script assumes linreg.Rscript in same directory
```

This is the first line of the linreg.R

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

I have tried setting path to `PATH=$PATH:C:\\ProgramFiles\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin`
but of no use. It has changed the PATH but still the script is not running.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: cygwin using unix path, you should give : `/cygwin/c/ProgramFiles/R/R-3-3.0.1/bin`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I tired this but its giving me the same error!! when I do `$which R` it gives me `which: no R in (..)`

Comment: my feeling, you installed windows version of R, but try to use in Unix. In windows, it is R.exe or racript.exe

Comment: @BMW.. yes you are write.. I never usedd Unix version of R and I work on Windows8. I could not get your point of R.exe . What should I do with R.exe? I changed the shebang of linreg.R to Rscript.exe but it si still showing me the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be worth your time to add it to your .bashrc file:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin' >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake that I was making again and again.

cygpath is used to find out the actual representation of the path of the the directory in UNIX environment

Example:

```
$ cygpath 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin'
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/R/R-3.0.1/bin
```

So we need to make sure that PATH variable has `Program Files` and not `ProgramFiles`. 
Since UNIX does not understand special characters we need to backscape the space between `Program Files`

```
 $ PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/R/R-3.0.1/bin
```

It started recognizing R files after that.

Comment: I set the PATH by going into Windows 7's environment variables. The PATH was correct on Cygwin, but I got "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". So close yet so far...

Comment: I tried it in my cygwin .bashrc first in a bunch of different ways, and when that didn't work, I went to Wndows 7 Advanced System Settings.

Comment: What does your `echo %PATH%` says? I am not sure how to check PATH variable in windows since I switched to Mac a long time ago.

Comment: The advanced system settings PATH is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\RAA\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64

Comment: `echo $PATH` in Cygwin spits out /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Rtools/bin:/cygdrive/c/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/RAA/R/R-3.3.0/bin/x64:/usr/lib/lapack

Comment: `ls  /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RAA/R/R-3.3.0/bin/x64/R.exe` in Cygwin spits out `'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/RAA/R/R-3.3.0/bin/x64/R.exe'`. I've tried three versions of `PATH` in Cygwin: (1) Program Files is quoted, (2) the space is escaped, and (3) Progra~1 is used instead. I've tried these both in Windows 7 advanced system settings and by appending to the `PATH` in `.bashrc` for Cygwin.

Comment: I had to call R.exe directly to get it working..     /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/R/R-4.0.3/bin/R.exe    And then just made an alias rpg ="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/R/R-4.0.3/bin/R.exe" in my ~/.bashrc to get it working.